# Command running on terminal but not on crontab

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, cron

I'm trying to run the following commands on a crontab but for some reason I don't know it doesn't. However, it runs when I run it on the terminal.

```
IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find /path/to/folder/  -maxdepth 1 -printf '\%T@ \%p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n)
file="${line#* }"
```

I'm trying to use it to find the oldest directory on a certain path.

Can someone please help me correct it? If it's not too much to ask already an explanation would help a lot as well! Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is what I have from `crontab -e`

`*/1 16 * * * /path/to/script/test.sh`

And here is my script

```
min_dirs=3

mkdir /path/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M)

[[ $(find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l) -ge $min_dirs ]] &&
IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find /path/  -maxdepth 1 -printf '\%T@ \%p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n)
file="${line#* }"

rm -rf "$file"
```

What I want to do is start deleting the oldest directory when there a fill others already hence the min_dirs variable

Comment: cron runs using `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`.  I'm not a shell expert but I think I see at least one bash-specific thing in there.

Comment: So, if I registered a bash /path/to/script.sh instead of just /path/to/script.sh it could work?

Comment: @MauricioZaparoli are you running a *script* from your crontab, or running the command directly from your crontab? If the former, does the script have an appropriate `#!/bin/bash` shebang?

Comment: @steeldriver, I'm a beginner on crontab so I don't know which one it is. But I used the crontab -e to do this. But with no #!/bin/bash shebang

Comment: To clear this up a bit easier, can you please edit your question and post the contents of your crontab?

Comment: @BrianTurek, it's edited!

Comment: Try adding `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file and make sure the script's permissions allow at least read+execute. Are those enclosing backticks a part of your script or just markup problems?

Comment: I'll do that. They are a part of it but might be causing some issues. I was googling for a way to correct my problem and saw someone say that for crontab we should use "\" before "%"

Comment: I added the #!/bin/bash and removed the "\"s. Thank you, @BrianTurek

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this all works now, here's a summary:

`cron` executes using `/bin/sh` as opposed to `/bin/bash`.  I'm not a bash expert but I think I see at least one thing in your script that `/bin/sh` does not support.

Adding a `#!/bin/bash` line to the top of your script (often called a "shebang") indicates that the script should be executed with that executable (it can be more than shells, you can also specify Python).  This should solve the problem of running bash code under `/bin/sh`.

I don't know if it's causing you issues but surrounding you whole script with backticks (`) is wholly unnecessary.